# URLs redirect to spyware site

Tags: iphone, facebook, url, google-chrome

We are developing an app that makes posts on behalf of our users to Facebook. Within those posts, we want to put links to external (non-Facebook) websites.

Looking at the links in the status bar of the browser (usually Chrome), the correct URL is displayed.  However, Facebook seems to wrap the actually-clicked link into some extra bells-and-whistles.  Usually, this works correctly.

Sometimes, however, this URL wrapping ends up sending the click to a URL like:

> http: //spywaresite.info/0/go.php?sid=2

(added space to make it non-browsable!) which generates Chromes severe warning message:

[image]

This happens very occasionally on Chrome, but very much more often in the iOS browser on the iPhone.

Does anyone have any pointers as to how to deal with this?

---

**EDIT**

For example, the URLs we put in the link is

> http://www.example.com/some/full/path/somewhere

but the URL that actually gets clicked is:

> http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=374274329267054&v=1&size=z&cksum=fc1c17ed464a92bc53caae79e5413481&src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsome%2Ffull%2Fpath%2Fsomewhere

There seems to be some JavaScript goodness in the page that unscrambles that and *usually* redirects correctly.

**EDIT2**

The links above are put on the image and the blue text to the right of the image in the screenshot below.

Mousing over the links (or the image) in the browser shows the correct link.  Right-clicking on the link and selecting "Copy Link Address" gets the fbcdn.net link above (or one like it).  Actually clicking on the link seems to set off some JavaScript processing of the fbcdn.net link into the right one...  but sometimes that processing fails.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here, but i'll tell you what I know:- are you referring to this screen on Facebook?

[image: Screenshot of interstitial]]
(or rather, the variation of that screen which doesn't allow clickthrough?)

- If you manually send a user to facebook.com/l.php?u=something they'll always see that message - it's a measure to prevent an open redirector

  - if your users are submitting such links, including the l.php link, you'll need to extract the destination URL (in the 'u' parameter)
  - If you're seeing the l.php URLs come back from the API this is probably a bug.

If links clicked *on* facebook.com end up on the screen it's because facebook have detected the link as suspicious (e.g. for URL redirector sites - the screen will allow clickthrough but warn the user first) or malicious/spammy (will not allow clickthrough)

In your app you won't be able to post links to the latter (an error will come back saying the URL is blocked), and the former may throw a captcha sometimes (if you're using the Feed dialog, this should be transparent to the app code, the user will enter the captcha and the dialog will return as normal)

If this isn't exactly what you were asking about please clarify and i'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks the the info!  That's not quite what I was after. The links we have go to `http://www.example.com` (i.e. a non-Facebook URL).  I haven't seen the dialog you show (at least, not in the testing I've been doing).

Comment: So what is the issue you're having? it wasn't entirely clear from the question what you were doing and what the problem was - i assumed you were either consuming links which turned out to be blocked by Facebook, or attempting to post links which turned out to be blocked

Comment: The issue is that the posts are showing up on my wall in Facebook, but the Facebook website seems to process the URLs when they are clicked.  This processing fails, and redirects to a completely unrelated and undesirable site.

Comment: That sounds very bad; if you have specific examples and/or repro steps could you file a bug and link it here please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ - danke - please make sure the steps can be followed to see the problem or it'll be difficult to get it prioritised :)

Comment: Understood!  Thanks for the link.  I'm going to try to put together a test case that does the right thing; that might take a little.  I'l try to get it done by later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add to the question, I thought I'd put more details here.

It looks like the Facebook mention in the original title was mis-directed, so I've removed it.

We still haven't got to the bottom of the issue.

However, we used both [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to look at the HTTP traffic between the Chrome browser (on the PC) and Facebook.  Both showed that Facebook was returning the correct URL refresh.

Here's what Wireshark showed:

[image]

What we saw on Fiddler was that our server is issuing a redirect to the spywaresite.info site:

[image]

We are working with our ISP to figure out what is happening here.

Comment: Is your site hosting a CMS of some kind? it's probably been compromised. I've seen hacked servers which when accessed directly were absolutely normal in appearance, but if you provided a 'Referer:' header of a Facebook URL it returned malicious content, so the original page owner didn't notice, but people clicking links on facebook were brought to the scam site

Comment: @Igy: Thanks! I'm still in the process of chasing this.  Not a happy camper; I will be once it's resolved.  Thanks heaps for your input, even if my data was a red herring.